# Add rb-grib gem to Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, operating-system

I'm new to Rails and I got a problem.

My new project requires `rb-grib` gem (link to ruby gems: `https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-grib/versions/0.2.2`). This gem requires `GRIB API` library, I installed it using `brew install grib-api`. It works in irb and .rb scripts. I need to use it in my Rails app, but I get an error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- numru/grib`. What I need to do to make it work and deploy to Heroku in future?

Comment: Have you added rb-grib in your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I added, but it do not help me

Comment: I decided problem by adding `require` to Rakefile.

Comment: How can I deploy this app to Heroku? How to install C libs remotely?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
require 'numru/grib'
```

Comment: should be a cooment